# How to Get system IP (IPv4) address and convert to string using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my web application I am using the following function to get System IP

**Function**

```
public void SetHostid()
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = "";
            string strHostName = "";
            strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

            IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

            ip = addr[1].MapToIPv4().ToString();

            HostId = ip;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Hostid"] = HostId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error_ManagerClass em = new Error_ManagerClass();
            em.WriteError(ex);
        }
    }
```

It works perfectly because the IP is on the 1 postion of the variable addr (`addr[ 1]`).
[image]

And the problem comes when I try to run the same solution from a different system. function throws an error while trynig to convert IP to string(  `ip = addr[1].MapToIPv4().ToString();` ) because IP is not in the position number 1.
[image]

how can I change the function to work on every computer ??

Comment: There is a host file in the c:\windows folder that contains the list of IP.  In your case you can use regex to get the IP that matches X.X.X.X.

Comment: "to get System IP" ... which one? I understand you want an IPv4 address. But looking at your 2nd example: which one? What should happen on Systems that only support IPv6 ?

Comment: if the host has multiple IP adresses, how do you decide which one to take?

Comment: Depending on a specific item of an array is surely not the good idea. You need to loop thru the array of IPAddress and check it's property `IsIPv4MappedToIPv6` before calling MapToIpv4 method.

Comment: Smells like X-Y-Problem. What do you want to do with that IP? `HostId` looks like you want to identify clients? In that case, maybe the MAC is a better option ... (while *not* being the "best"). You could also use client certificates or some combination of MAC, h/w -Serial numbers ... Shall that ID be valid across sessions or only for one session?

Comment: @Fildor i am trying to save only IPv4

Comment: The issue is a bit more complicated than *"Get my IP-Address"*. If you want it to *"work on every computer"* you need to take into account that a computer can have multiple network interfaces (e.g. Ethernet, Wifi, Cell, etc.) and every interface can potentially multiple addresses. A good first start would be to filter potential results with `IPAddress.IsLoopback` (to get rid of 127.0.0.1 and ::1) and `AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork` to get rid of non-IPv4 Addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get IPv4 only use this code:

```
var addr = ipEntry.AddressList.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

var firstInList = addr.First(); // get first
```

But you should consider which IP to chose when there are several IP addresses in system.

Comment: Think you need either `First` or `Single` to end your LINQ.

Comment: @JohnWu, It gets all IPv4 in system, then you should chose needed one